# Grafana doesn't recognize fields in Elasticsearch (Elastic Cloud)

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, elastic-cloud

I am trying out **Elastic Cloud**. I want to connect to **Elasticsearch** in **Grafana**

However, I have a field named **timestamp** in my index. Grafana doesn't recognize it.

[image]

[image]

Things I did :  1) I tried `timestamp' instead of @timestamp
                2) I tried all the different version. 
                3) I tried different indexes.

But all no good. :(

[image]
[image]

**Grafana doesn't seem to recognize fields in an index. What could be causing this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The message is a bug. 
>   You can just ignore it, and continue.

Also, if you want, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55758705/1050) will give you more information.

[image]
[image]